# Why does firefox differentiates between same url with WWW keyword

Tags: firefox

I have a Firefox bookmark with tags
www.processing.org/

I see a gold star in the address bar indicating that the url is boomarked.

However when I key in the URL processing.org (without the WWW) the bookmark icon does not show up.

Essentially both open up the same page.
My question is why can't firefox figure it out? Is there a settings change I need to do?

[image: With bookmark icon]
[image: without book mark icon]

Comment: What he said. Note that www is not a keyword, it has no special meaning other than that it (usually) goes to the home directory, by convention rather than by mandate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, they are *technically* different URL's. It's possible to have `www.processing.org` and `processing.org` point to different locations/servers/web sites. From a usability standpoint it wouldn't make any sense to do that, but it's not impossible.

I would guess they chose the safe route and designed the bookmarks to be completely dumb in order to accommodate any not-so-intelligently designed web sites. They make no other assumptions other than "does this URL string match this URL string?" Bookmarks won't even match a sub-directory under the same domain (ex: `http://processing.org/banana`).

If there are settings tucked away in about:config to enable a more intelligent Bookmark URL checking system, I can't find them. You might try looking for a relevant add-on.